# How to make a static graph embedded in tkinter frame dynamic?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the challenge I'm facing.

I want to visualize an array, which will be filled with randomly generated numbers in every loop.

I have a script, that DOES show a dynamical graph, but which isn't embedded in the tkinter window. On the other hand, I have another script, that IS embedded inside a tkinter frame, but I fail to merge the needed things into one script due to the fact that the scripts use a different way to plot the graph.

Here is the script that plots dynamically, but isn't embedded in the window:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    window = tk.Tk()
    plt.axis([-50,50,0,10000])
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
    while True:
    #for pow in range(1,50):   # plot x^1, x^2, ..., x^4
        plt.cla()
        y = 5*np.random.rand(50)
        plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.001)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is the second code:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,
NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import serial
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,1,101)
#print(len(x))
def main():
    fig = Figure(figsize = (5, 5), dpi = 100)
    y = [i**2 for i in range(101)]
    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plot1.plot(x, y)
    #The canvas the figure is drawn on:
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

window = Tk()
window.title('Plotting in Tkinter')
window.geometry("500x500")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'd really like the first code, because it uses fewer lines of code and looks cleaner, but I'm open for any bone that's thrown in.

Comment: embeding dynamic plot in tkinter was few times. Some examples even read data from serial port. It may need to use `window.after(1000, update_plot)` to run every 1000ms own function `update_plot()` and in this function you can add new values ot `plot.data`.

Comment: you have to use `window.mainloop()` to keep running tkinter - without mainloop it ends code and you can't update it.

Comment: `import *` is not preferred

Answer (score 0):

This problem was few times on Stackoverflow.

It needs to use `window.after(milliseconds, function)` to execute function after some time and this function has to create new plot or replace `ydata` in line on plot (it may work faster)
.

Code also needs `window.mainloop()` to run loop which gets key/mouse events from system, sends data to widgets, and finally redraw all widgets in window. Without this loop tkinter ends work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,
NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def update_plot():
    
    y = 5 * np.random.rand(50)
    lines[0].set_ydata(y)
    canvas.draw()
    
    window.after(25, update_plot)  # run again after 25ms (1000ms/25ms = 40 FPS (frames per second))
    
def main():
    global window
    global canvas
    global lines
    
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, 50)
    y = 5 * np.random.rand(50)

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title('Plotting in Tkinter')
    window.geometry("500x500")

    #The canvas the figure is drawn on:
    fig = Figure(figsize = (5, 5), dpi = 100)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    lines = plot1.plot(x, y)

    #window.after(25, update_plot)  # run first time after 25ms
    update_plot()  # run first time at once

    window.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this with a more streamlined way? The way with FigureCanvasTkAgg looks very messy. I'd like to leave out the canvas alltogether and simply place the plot onto the tkinter window. The extrastep using a canvas seems obsolete.

Comment: you can't do this without `FigureCanvasTkAgg` - it uses widget `tkinter.Canvas` to display plot (lines, dots, rectangles, images, etc.) in tkinter window. And this need special tkinter functions to draw every elment on Canvas. If you would like to do it without `FigureCanvasTkAgg` then you would have to create it from scratch and this would be very complex task. But you have to create `FigureCanvasTkAgg` only once and later you can use `plot()`, `scatter()`, etc to display in this canvas.

Comment: and the same is when you use other GUIs - PyQt, wxPython, etc. - you have to create special widget to display it in PyQt, wxPython, etc. and later you can use standard functions `plot()`, `scatter()`, `cla()`

Comment: see matplotlib documentation for: [Embedding in Tk](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html), [Embedding in Qt](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html), etc. And this is official method to do it - it is NOT obsolete.

Comment: Thank's for the abundant feedback. As a beginner I'm thankful for every bit of info to learn from it.